# How to control number of shards in Elastic index from logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, controls, sharding

I would like to control how many shards a new index should have in my logstash output file. Ex:

10-output.conf:

```
output {
    if [type] == "mytype" {
    elasticsearch {
       hosts => [ "1.1.1.1:9200"  ]
       index => "logstash-mytype-%{+YYYY.ww}"
       workers => 8
       flush_size => 1000
       ? <====== what option to control the number of index shards goes here?
    }
}
```

From what I understand in [logstash elastic options](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.4/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html) this is not possible and new index will default to 5 shards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Logstash-Elasticsearch mix it's designed to work differently than what your expectation is: in Elasticsearch one defines an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/indices-templates.html) in which the number or shards is a configuration setting.

And whenever Logstash creates a new index by sending documents to this new index, Elasticsearch uses that index template (by matching the new index name with the configured template) to actually create the index.

Comment: Indeed.  One of the most fundamental misunderstandings is that Logstash creates indices.  It doesn't.  Logstash sends a bulk request to Elasticsearch that is the equivalent of, "please put these documents into an index named logstash-YYYY.MM.dd" and Elasticsearch creates the index if it does not exist.  At no point ever does Logstash issue a API call to create an index.  As such, as Andrei Stefan pointed out, the only way to control shard count and other settings is through index templates.